# Bundler won't find puma when deploying Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, puma

Just FYI, this is the first time I'm deploying something on a production server. I went through this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) as my server is also hosted on DO.

The environment is pretty much the same - I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Ruby 2.3.3 (rbenv) and rails 5.

I followed everything step by step and I have gotten no error, however, now I'm getting a 502 bad gateway when accessing my public IP.

I have noticed that for some reason after starting puma manager (sudo start puma-manager), the directory "shared/sockets/puma.sock" is not getting created.

When I start puma manually by using -> RACK_ENV=production bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb from my app directory, I get the following error:

bundler: failed to load command: puma (/root/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/puma)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - connect(2) for /root/belooga/shared/sockets/puma.sock

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? Should you need to see any file, please let me know and I'll provide anything that might be needed.

Cheers!

EDIT:

I have double-checked all the paths in:

- myapp/config/puma.rb
- /etc/puma.conf
- /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the directory "shared/sockets/puma.sock" is not getting created.

Here is your problem, create the directory before you start the puma server.